# Unable to set a dim background to a modal view

Tags: ios, uiview, background, modal-dialog, opacity

I'm developing an app targeting `iOS` 7 and above. I'd like to present modally a view with a dim background that partially shows the previous view below. I've read several posts dealing with this scenario, and I did:

1. Created a view controller scene in `storyboard` and set a modal segue to navigate to it.
2. Set the `Presentation` value of that modal segue to `Current Context`.
3. Set the view controller's view background color to clear color.
4. Added a full-screen view above the parent view, with black color background and 50% opacity.

Transition to the modal view is default and animated. While the animation, I see the view being presented as semi-transparent, but once the transition animation ends and view finally occupies the full screen, the view becomes opaque black.

What I'm doing wrong? How could I solve this?

Comment: just a note regarding the last statement: it probably does not become opaque but the view in the back is no longer rendered, the one in the front is still transparent, but there is no longer anything behind it to be shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @luk2302 said, when you present a view controller modally, iOS removes the view controllers underneath it from the view hierarchy so is nothing underneath it except the app window, which is black. Anyway, iOS 7 has a new modal presentation style, UIModalPresentationCustom, that forces iOS not to remove the views underneath the presented view controller. But you must provide your own transition delegate to handle the presentation and dismiss animations
Check [this link](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/?id=218) how to implement custom transition delegate.

Comment: And if the modal view I want to present has no more purpose than showing a message to the user and being dismissed, should it be actually preferable just to create a view and add it above the current one?

Comment: No, the view controller is still there, it simply is not rendered.

Comment: That's why I'm thinking that just adding the subviews I want to the current view and view controller, without displaying a model view with its own view controller... should work, right? I only want to display a sort of alert with dim background and with a custom dismiss button...

Comment: The easiest and simplest solution. But not that elegant though. Just use `bringSubviewToFront:` method to bring the dimmed background on top of everything. You can send it back to the bottom of the hierarchy by using `sendSubviewToBack:` method when needed.